# CXF 3 Memory Leak

Tags: jaxb, cxf

I have a web service created from a wsdl and have not changed anything, so all I have is an empty application.

After deploying the app, as soon as I click 'stop' (i.e. I have not even called it), I get 'SEVERE' messages from Tomcat and the leak tests reports my app as having multiple instances, and increases every time I stop/start.

I am using CXF 3.1.0 and have even tried downloading the very latest JAXB (reference implementation from website).

The error is as follows:

```
    org.apache.cxf.workqueue.AutomaticWorkQueueImpl$AWQThreadFactory$1.run(Automati
    cWorkQueueImpl.java:353)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    11-Jun-2015 15:45:33.142 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.loade
    r.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [MyAcces
    sAPSServiceN] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassF
    actory$1] (value [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory$1@27765bfc]) and a value of t
    ype [java.util.WeakHashMap] (value [{class org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.Attribut
    edURIType=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@4b9111a1}]) but failed to remove it when t
    he web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try
    and avoid a probable memory leak.
    11-Jun-2015 15:45:33.143 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.loade
    r.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [MyAcces
    sAPSServiceN] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassF
    actory$1] (value [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory$1@27765bfc]) and a value of t
    ype [java.util.WeakHashMap] (value [{class org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.wsdl.Hell
    oType=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@211c87c9, class javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CE
    ndpointReference$Address=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@5816ae1a, class javax.xml.w
    s.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@39005a24, class
    org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.wsdl.ScopesType=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@461e0eb8
    , class java.util.ArrayList=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@5f5875fe, class javax.xm
    l.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference$Elements=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@28aa
    a799}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads ar
    e going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
    11-Jun-2015 15:45:33.146 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.loade
    r.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [MyAcces
    sAPSServiceN] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassF
    actory$1] (value [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory$1@27765bfc]) and a value of t
    ype [java.util.WeakHashMap] (value [{class org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.Attribut
    edURIType=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@5be142aa}]) but failed to remove it when t
    he web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try
    and avoid a probable memory leak.
    11-Jun-2015 15:45:33.148 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.loade
    r.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [MyAcces
    sAPSServiceN] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassF
    actory$1] (value [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory$1@27765bfc]) and a value of t
    ype [java.util.WeakHashMap] (value [{class javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpoint
    Reference$Address=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@21dfd606, class javax.xml.ws.wsadd
    ressing.W3CEndpointReference=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@6e5c3549, class org.apa
    che.cxf.ws.discovery.wsdl.ScopesType=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@67ae8439, class
    java.util.ArrayList=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@726aef5c, class org.apache.cxf.
    ws.discovery.wsdl.ByeType=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@4a88bbb3, class javax.xml.
    ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference$Elements=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@56db0a
    ff}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are
    going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a [known limitation of the JAXB API](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-1000). Issue claims you can avoid the problem by explicitly closing the Unmarshaller, but I haven't tried that myself.

Comment: I'm using CFX so have no access to this low level I believe.